# Ошибка которую не видит браузер

Tags: вёрстка, html, dreamweaver

Разробатываю сайт на `Adobe Dreamweaver CS6`, главное браузер не выдаёт ошибки, код правильный а `Adobe` выдаёт вот исходник

```
<p align="CENTER"
<font style="font-size: 20pt"><a href="niz/site.html" textov </font>
</p> 
</a>

<h5 align="center">
  <a href="niz/site.html"><u><i> О сайте </i></u></a><a href="niz/razrabotchiki.html"alt="Разработчик Суворов Арсентий"><u><i>Разработчики</i></u></a><i><a href="niz/vakansii.html"> Вакансии</a></i> <u><!-- текст нижней шапки--> 
</u></h5>
<p align="center">
<a href="niz/form.html"<i>form</i></p></a>
```

Ругается Adob на

```
p align="CENTER"
```

Типо недопустимый потому что отсутствует закрывающая кавычка либо скобка (хотя это не так).
Ругается на `<a href="niz/site.html" textov` , ошибка такая же как и выше 
И на это так-же `<a href="niz/form.html"` 
А браузер отображает нормально.

Comment: align разве не устарело ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мсье Programist Syvorov не исправим. 
Предлагаю загадку:

Наидите отличия между этой

```
<p align="CENTER" <font style="font-size: 20pt"><a href="niz/site.html" textov </font> </p> </a>
```

и этой записью

```
<p align="CENTER"> <font style="font-size: 20pt"><a href="niz/site.html"> textov   </a></font></p>
```

И еще совет: не стоит начинать изучение html со всяких "дримвиверов" - работа учебником,  блокнотом и ручками лучше развивает память головы и пальцев.

Comment: <p align="CENTER"  Скобки нету , код не сработает абра кадабра в браузере так ?

Comment: Да скобка, + к этому еще желательно привыкнуть следить за вложенностью тегов.

Answer (score 8):

> что отсутствует закрывающая кавычка
> либо скобка(хотя это не так)

А первая же строка - это разве не отсутствие "закрывающей скобки"? А в самом конце вашего кода, в теге <a> разве весь синтаксис соблюден?

> А браузер отоброжает нормально .

Браузер понял, что дороже будет с вами бороться. Вот и отображает якобы нормально ))

Comment: У меня вконце всё закрываеться </p> </a> Браузер на такую конструкцию реагирует нормально а Adobe не очень ...

Comment: @Programist Syvorov, я понять не могу - вы шутите так или серьёзно говорите?

Comment: А как правильней будет ведь на <p align="CENTER" и на всё остальное реагирует норм, А Adob нет ... Может не обращать на ошибку, я много раз проверял свою конструкцию в браузере работает нормально, может в синтаксиме Abobe  это плохо ?

Comment: Мсье Браузер всё видит, просто мсье браузер снисходителен. Поддерживаю Deonis и высказываю предположение, что кнопочка с ">" недожимает. Такое бывает если часто "кушать овсянку" перед компьютером сэээр!

Comment: > Может не обращать на ошибку> может в синтаксиме Abobe это плохо@Programist Syvorov, а может для начала, почитать про [основы html](http://htmlbook.ru/html)

Comment: Прохорёнка Н.А я читаю Задаю параметры там center шрифт ссылки и.т.d  и всё норм а в этой строчке ошибка ладно сам разберусь....

Comment: @Programist Syvorov, не знаю кто такой Прохорёнко, но если после прочтения, вы такие грубейшие ошибки делаете, то эту книгу в топку. Хотя, не исключаю, что это вы так "читаете", а не он так пишет.

Comment: Я просто закоментировал <!--<p align="CENTER"
<font style="font-size: 20pt"><a href="niz/site.html" textov </font>
</p> 
</a> --> И вот это : <!--<a href="niz/form.html"<i>form</i></p></a> --> И ошибки ушли, всё равно всем спасибо за отклик ... !!

Comment: Вам пытались объяснить, что в тэге `p` `<p align="CENTER"` не хватает угловой закрывающей скобки `>`. И эта ошибка далее повторяется.

Comment: @Димка ахахахахахахаахахаха я очень долго смеялся.... 
Ну а в качестве совета автору вопроса рекомендую открыть исходный код простеньких сайтов и просто по изучать что как и к чему в нем